# Java 8 Streams Nested ForEach with different conditions

Tags: java, foreach, collections, java-stream

i'm totally new to java 8 streams. just want know how to write the below code using java stream api. Not sure on how to write nested loops with filters to map the data.

```
public AccountByCustomerDto getAccountDetails(int customerId, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    List<Accountowner> accountOwnerList = repo.getAccountOwners(customerId);
    List<AccountByCustomerDto.AccountDto> aDtoList = new ArrayList<AccountByCustomerDto.AccountDto>();
    
    for (Accountowner accountOwner : accountOwnerList) {        
        String currency = accountOwner.getAccount1().getAccountCurrency();
        if(accountOwner != null && currency.startsWith("USD")) {                
            List<Accountbalance> accountBalanceList = accountOwner.getAccount1().getAccountbalances();
            List<AccountByCustomerDto.BalancesDto> balanceDtoList = new ArrayList<AccountByCustomerDto.BalancesDto>();
            for (Accountbalance balance : accountBalanceList) {
                String creditInclude = balance.getCreditLimitIncluded();
                if(balance != null && creditInclude.equals("Y")) {
                    
                    AccountByCustomerDto.BalancesDto balanceDto = AccountByCustomerDto.BalancesDto.builder()
                            .balanceType(balance.getBalanceType()).baDto(null)                              
                            .referenceDate(
                                    balance.getReferenceDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate())                                
                            .build();
                    balanceDtoList.add(balanceDto);
                }                   
            }
            String accountId = Integer.toString(accountOwner.getAccount1().getAccountId()) + ":"
                    + accountOwner.getAccount1().getAccountCurrency();
            AccountByCustomerDto.AccountDto adto = AccountByCustomerDto.AccountDto.builder()
                    .accountId(Utility.encrypt(accountId))
                    .accountNumberDisplay(accountOwner.getAccount1().getAccountDisplay())
                    .balances(balanceDtoList).accountLink(null).build();
            aDtoList.add(adto);
        }           
    }
    return AccountByCustomerDto.builder().accounts(aDtoList).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think just switching the code to `Stream` would make the code even less readable. So when one method gets very long it's a good idea to split it into smaller methods.
When the code is split up into smaller methods streams provide a real benefit when it comes to readability compared to traditional loops.

Element in stream remains in stream if `accountOwnerCurrencyIsUSD` is true. The remaining elements are mapped to a `AccountDto` using `createAccountDto` and the result is collected into a `AccountDto` list. Is much easier to read than create list, loop through other list, get currency, check currency, create another list...

```
public AccountByCustomerDto getAccountDetails(int customerId, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {    
    List<AccountByCustomerDto.AccountDto> aDtoList = accountOwnerList.stream()
        .filter(this::accountOwnerCurrencyIsUSD)
        .map(this::createAccountDto)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return AccountByCustomerDto.builder().accounts(aDtoList).build();
}

private AccountCustomerDto.AccountDto createAccountDto(Accountowner owner) {
    String accountId = accountOwner.getAccount1().getAccountId() + ":" + accountOwner.getAccount1().getAccountCurrency();
    List<AccountByCustomerDto.BalancesDto> balanceDtoList = accountOwner.getAccount1().getAccountbalances()
        .stream()
        .filter(this::includesCredit)
        .map(this::createBalanceDto)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return AccountByCustomerDto.AccountDto.builder()
        .accountId(Utility.encrypt(accountId))         
        .accountNumberDisplay(accountOwner.getAccount1().getAccountDisplay())
        .balances(balanceDtoList)
        .accountLink(null)
        .build();
}

private AccountByCustomerDto.BalancesDto createBalanceDto(Accountbalance balance) {
    return AccountByCustomerDto.BalancesDto.builder()
        .balanceType(balance.getBalanceType())
        .baDto(null)
        .referenceDate(alance.getReferenceDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate())
        .build();
}

private boolean accountOwnerCurrencyIsUSD(Accountowner owner) {
    return accountOwner != null && "USD".eqauls(accountOwner.getAccount1().getAccountCurrency());
}

private boolean includesCredit(Accountbalance balance) {
    return balance != null && "Y".equals(balance.getCreditLimitIncluded());
}
```

I have not way to test the code, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks. since im totally new to stream API this was actually very much help me to understand how to use stream API.